# Scala Play Guice using injector to manually inject a singleton class that has configuration injected into its constructor

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

using play 2.5 and guice i have managed to successfully inject applicationConfig into a singleton class and reference a config variable inside it,

```
trait TMongoFactory{
  val SERVER: String
  val PORT: Int
  val DATABASE: String
  val connection: MongoClient
  val collection: MongoDB
}

@Singleton
class MongoFactory @Inject()(val configuration: Configuration) extends TMongoFactory{
  val SERVER = "localhost"         
  val PORT = 27017
  val DATABASE = configuration.underlying.getString("connectionString")
  val connection = MongoClient(SERVER, PORT)  
  val collection = connection(DATABASE)
}


class MongoModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[TMongoFactory]).to(classOf[MongoFactory])
  }
}
```

I can then pass this singleton to a repository class like so

```
@Singleton
class MongoRemainingAllowanceRepository @Inject()(MongoFactory: TMongoFactory) extends RemainingAllowanceRepository{
  val context = MongoFactory.collection("remainingAllowance")
  def save(remainingAllowance: RemainingAllowance): Unit ={
    context.save(RemainingAllowance.convertToMongoObject(remainingAllowance))
  }
```

This all works fine and as expected, but the problem is i need to call this repository in the test suite so i dont want it to have to take any arguments (specifically injected ones).
So i tried to change it to use an injector inside the body like so

```
@Singleton
class MongoRemainingAllowanceRepository extends RemainingAllowanceRepository{
  val injector = Guice.createInjector(new MongoModule)
  val mongoFactory = injector.getInstance(classOf[TMongoFactory])

  val context = mongoFactory.collection("remainingAllowance")
  def save(remainingAllowance: RemainingAllowance): Unit ={
    context.save(RemainingAllowance.convertToMongoObject(remainingAllowance))
  }
```

This feels like it should work and it compiles fine, but then on test or run it throws an error

```
Could not find a suitable constructor in play.api.Configuration. Classes
must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject
or a zero-argument constructor that is not private. at
play.api.Configuration.class(Configuration.scala:173) while locating
play.api.Configuration
```

Apologies for the long post but i feel i needed to include most of this.
Does anyone know why this happens on an injector? Do i need to bind the configuration manually also now im referencing the custom module?

Any help appreciated
Thanks
Jack

Comment: Why can't you provide the arguments in the test suite? What type of test is this ? Is Guice/Play app running in the test?

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for the reply, I don't believe the app is running as part of the test no, it is a Playspec, if there was a way to load the application and for guide to run that would work too yes, i just don't know how.

Comment: Ok i think then it should work can send a gist but going to be away from keyboard for a while ..i did something similar in my own app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your class you can pass in the configuration yourself. Say you need key `apiKey` and its value...

```
val sampleConfig = Map("apiKey" ->"abcd1234")
val mongoFactory = new MongoFactory(Configuration.from(sampleConfig))
```

Comment: Barry you are a legend! i was seriously overthinking this issue, such a great little way to solve it, thank you sir :)